# How can I find out where an executable on my favorites bar is located?

Tags: unity, favorites

On Windows the shortcuts can be right clicked and when properties is selected it will show you a window which tells you where the executable target is located.

I have a favorites bar which has a program on it that has at least 3 possible locations (don't ask - it's a mess) and I'd like to know which one the icon is pointing to. I tried the "details" item on the right-click menu and it shows nothing but "no application found".

How can I find out where the link is pointing?

Thanks!
Sean

Comment: Check out `alacarte` (might need to install it). It will show you all your desktop shortcuts and you can see for each icon "Properties" -> "command".

Comment: @pLumo - thanks for that. I installed it but I found it did not present me with the favorites  bar but it was a bit of a long shot. It DOES have a wealth of info which indirectly led me to the actual item I was interested in :-) Much appreciated!

Comment: I wrote an answer with some more information, glad that it was helpful

Comment: @pLumo - got it and see below...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The favorite apps are saved as `dconf` setting, you can read it with:

```
dconf read "/org/gnome/shell/favorite-apps"
```

This will print out a list of ".desktop" files, e.g.

```
['nemo.desktop', 'firefox_firefox.desktop', 'thunderbird.desktop', 'some-program.desktop']
```

To find the real location of your `some-program.desktop`, try

```bash
locate "some-program.desktop"
```

or search in the following locations, if `locate` can not find it or is not installed:

```bash
~/.local/share/applications
/usr/share/applications
/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications
```

To find the command to your icon, `grep` for `Exec` or use `cat`.

```bash
locate "some-program.desktop" | xargs grep ^Exec
```

### GUI only alternative

Run `dconf Editor`, find `/org/gnome/shell/favorite-apps` and check out the name of your `.desktop` file. Then, run `alacarte` ("Main Menu") (might need to install) and find that icon, right-click -> "Properties" will show you the command.

Comment: thanks again! I have not tried the GUI version but the command line version worked like a charm!

Comment: oh, and since I'm new here, I can't formally upvote your answers so consider it done :-)

Comment: @SeanMcGhee you may not be able to upvote, but as the question asker, you can do something more important: "accept" the question: click the checkmark on the left of the question. This shows other users a helpful answer can be found here.

Comment: `locate` is not anymore by default installed on Ubuntu. You may also mention that there is a priority in the locations: if `.desktop` files with the same name exist in multiple places, the one found in the first searched directory will be used

Comment: @vanadium - accepted!